# How to screen capture a DIV filled with dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I've been asked to create a page with a form on it that users can fill in, but there has been many little details that he wants.

Basically, I have scanned a form document on to the computer, saved it as a .jpg and uploaded it on to a page on the site. Then I created textboxes and used CSS to position them over the places where you should be able to write on the 'paper'

I can't show you too much of the form due to subtle details, but here's a part of what it looks like:

[image]

The form is obviously bigger than that, and I've placed the form image and textboxes all into one DIV called 'print'

After completing the form, I want the user to be able to press a button and either be able to print off ONLY the content inside the DIV, or be able to save ONLY the content inside the DIV as an image so that they can email it. I don't want anything else from the website like the header or footer or other body content to be viewable when printed or saved as an image, JUST the form with the stuff the user has filled out

Is there any possible way to do this or is there a simpler way I could be doing this?

Comment: Uhm, well, you could of course submit the form, save it in a database, or do other fun things with it like creating a PDF file that looks exactly like the 'paper' version. Screen capturing a form is - I guess - the somewhat unusual approach.

Comment: I want the approach to be rather simple for the user, where they just press a button and it's available for them to download - although yeah I could do that. Unless I could somehow retrieve the text values from the textboxes and place them in the correct places onto the form as a flat image?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a separate print style. Maybe a new CSS file that only displays the text that has been entered into your form fields. Make a new CSS reference to your file in the `<head>` section and add  `media="print"` - these styles will be used when the user prints from their browser. This might get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the help - I can't test it out right now as I'm busy doing stuff and also forgot to send over my FTP details from work to my home computer - but I'll give it a go when I have time!